# S&P 500 total return excel sheet

Tags: data-request, stock-market, financial-markets

Where can I find an excel sheet with total return (that is, with dividend reinvestment) of the S&P 500?

I have only found an online "calculator" (not an excel sheet), or an excel sheet with prices only (not adjusted for dividends).

Answer (score 1):

The Adj Close column of [Yahoo Finance's historical data section](https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/%5EGSPC/history?p=%5EGSPC) might be what you're looking for. It has the closing price adjusted for both dividends and splits, which could be used to calculate total return between any two dates. Just click Download Data to get it in an Excel readable format.